# Load from database by clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Using AngularJS functionality, I query objects (each having a 'number' field) in a database

```
<article class='recipe' ng-cloak ng-repeat='recipe in recipes'>
  <h2>
     <a data-ng-bind="recipe.number"></a>
  </h2>
</article>
```

that displays a list of 'recipe.number':

```
 d024b8f1-a278-401d-9fd5-a72458a42dd8
 0f647d45-607c-40a7-8dae-daea7385ea3f
 49580ae2-54ea-491a-89ad-7035a8e10e0e
 ...
```

Could you please advise me - how can I, by clicking on the displayed numbers, display another object's field (e.g. 'recipe.text')? Thank you.

Comment: something like (click)="displayText(reciepe)" inside the <a /> Tag?

Comment: please tell me how to display another field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Lotus91's answer: 
If you want to show one recipe at a time:

```
<article class='recipe' ng-cloak ng-repeat='recipe in recipes'>
  <h2>
    <a data-ng-bind="recipe.number" ng-click="showRecipe = recipe.text"></a>
  </h2>
</article>

<div ng-if="showRecipe != ''">
  <p>{{showRecipe}}</p>
</div>
```

OR, if you want to show more than one at a time:

```
<article class='recipe' ng-cloak ng-repeat='recipe in recipes'>
  <h2>
    <a data-ng-bind="recipe.number" ng-click="recipe.showRecipe = ! recipe.showRecipe"></a>
  </h2>
  <div ng-if="recipe.showRecipe">
    {{recipe.text}}
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like the following :

```
<article class='recipe' ng-cloak ng-repeat='recipe in recipes'>
  <h2>
    <a data-ng-bind="recipe.number" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails"></a>
  </h2>
  <div ng-show="showDetails">
    <p>{{recipe.text}}</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

When you click on the number you show the details and when you click one more time it hides the details.

Comment: this is wrong, because if you have a list of 100 numbers it will show the details of all numbers if you click it

Comment: You can fix this by adding a showDetails boolean to each specific recipe and directing the ng-show (or ng-if) to recipe.showDetails. Ofcourse also edit the ng-click to match. Either that, or make a div outside of the ng-repeat and create a variable that you overwrite with the recipe.text of the recipe.number that you clicked on.

Comment: @Lotus91 Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Is this you want?

```
<article class='recipe' ng-cloak ng-repeat='recipe in recipes'>
  <h2>
     <a data-ng-bind="recipe.number">{{recipe.text}}</a>
  </h2>
</article>
```